# UIBezierPath put one color for each piece resulting in just last color

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I want to put a one color for each piece. I added:

```
let colors = [
    [54.0/255.0, 78.0/255.0 ,44.0/255.0 ],
    [252.0/255.0, 178.0/255.0, 141.0/255.0 ],
    [242.0/255.0, 44.0/255.0 ,173.0/255.0 ],
    [239.0/255.0, 42.0/255.0 , 93.0/255.0 ],
    [169.0/255.0, 145.0/255.0, 135.0/255.0],
    [122.0/255.0, 228.0/255.0, 140.0/255.0],
    [110.0/255.0, 134.0/255.0, 36.0/255.0,],
    [32.0/255.0, 143.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0,],
    [178.0/255.0, 78.0/255.0, 6.0/255.0,],
    [39.0/255.0, 53.0/255.0, 27.0/255.0,],
    [46.0/255.0, 122.0/255.0, 151.0/255.0,],
]


let points = [[270, 290],[300, 320],[330, 350],[0, 20],[30, 50],[60, 80],[90, 110],[120, 140],[150, 170],[180, 200],[210, 230],[240, 260]]
func drawSmallCircles(){
    let index = 0
    for oneArray in points {
        let startAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[0]))
        let endAngleRadiant: CGFloat = degreesToRadians(Double(oneArray[1]))
        let radius: CGFloat = 50.0
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(100), y: CGFloat(100)),
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: startAngleRadiant,
            endAngle: endAngleRadiant,
            clockwise: true)
        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors[index][0]), green: CGFloat(colors[index][1]), blue: CGFloat(colors[index][2]), alpha: CGFloat(1))
        color.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = CGFloat(10)
        path.stroke()
    }
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    self.opaque = false;
    drawSmallCircles()
}
```

but just last color always show.

#### Update1

i forget to call
index++

but when i do that i got htis error:

/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of WaitingCircleView: Rendering the view took longer than 200 ms. Your drawing code may suffer from slow performance.

Comment: i find the color is always the first color, not the last color

Comment: Is this IBDesignable? Assuming it is, does it need to be? If not, turn off IBDesignable. If it really has to be designable, did you put you IBDesignable in its own module or is this all in a single module?

Comment: @Rob it is not necssary to be IBDesignable i think, i just put that in order to see it on the screen. the module place is empty, i should add some text to that module? teacher don't talk about this field

Comment: i find the error, it is because the number of colors not the same as poitns, wow it is working now, thank thank you very much. i really thank you. if u come to italy/milano, you are always have host. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intended

```
var index = 0
```

And, inside the loop:

```
index++
```

Comment: i find that and i got already another error i put the quesiton, please look for me? last thing realy because i have to do this homework for after 4 hours and i need sleep

Comment: i find that even if i commit the stock functions, i keep having that performacne error, maybe because of the the floating ?

Comment: when i remove the index++ the error performance go, but when i add it, the error performance come again :( :( :(

Comment: help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791680/cant-change-the-button-color-when-not-selected

Comment: hello please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026142/why-the-data-is-not-populated-in-my-custom-ui-table-view-cell

Comment: hello, how are you ?, please could you look for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245150/how-to-fire-the-tabs-in-a-custom-uitab-bar ?

Comment: No offense, but I'd respectfully ask that you stop posting comments to have me look at other questions immediately after you post them. If you post a question and don't receive any answers for a few days, send me a note on my web site listed on my profile, but I'd rather not get a comment immediately after you post a new question. I appreciate the confidence that you are conveying, but the community is large enough that others can help you, too. If you want on-going personal attention, we can set up a paid consulting arrangement. :)