# why the data is not populated in my custom ui table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting data from the server and i want to put it in my custom UITableViewCell

this is the cell in the story board

[image]

as you see there are two things:

1. The preferences label
2. three buttons

when i receive the data from the server, i do this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OneResponseTableViewCell") as! OneResponseTableViewCell
        let oneResponse = self.responses[indexPath.row]
        cell.preferencesLabel?.text = oneResponse.restaurantName
        print("row = \(indexPath.row), timesOptions = \(oneResponse.timeOptions)")
        if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 1{
            cell.firstTimeOption!.titleLabel?.text = oneResponse.timeOptions[0];
        }
        if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 2 {
            cell.secondTimeOption!.titleLabel?.text = oneResponse.timeOptions[1];
        }
        if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 3 {
            cell.thirdTimeOption!.titleLabel?.text = oneResponse.timeOptions[2];
        }
        return cell
    }
```

as you see, i am chaing the label and the buttons,

however, the buttons aren't being changed, please look at the result:

[image]

i tried to put **print** as you see in the code, and the data printed is correct, look please

```
row = 0, timesOptions = ["7:30 pm", "8:30 pm", "9:00 pm"]
row = 1, timesOptions = ["11:30 am", "12:00 pm", "12:30 pm"]
row = 2, timesOptions = ["7:30 pm", "8:30 pm", "9:00 pm"]
row = 3, timesOptions = ["7:30 pm", "8:30 pm", "9:00 pm"]
```

why it is not being correct in the cell?

sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting a button title, you should use `setTitle(forState:)`. For example:

```
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 1 {
    cell.firstTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[0], forState: .Normal)
}
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 2 {
    cell.secondTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[1], forState: .Normal)
}
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 3 {
    cell.thirdTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[2], forState: .Normal)
}
```

---

As an aside, because you are reusing cells, you really should check for the `else` clause for these `if` statements, hiding the button if it fails:

```
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 1 {
    cell.firstTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[0], forState: .Normal)
    cell.firstTimeOption.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.firstTimeOption.hidden = true
}
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 2 {
    cell.secondTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[1], forState: .Normal)
    cell.secondTimeOption.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.secondTimeOption.hidden = true
}
if oneResponse.timeOptions.count >= 3 {
    cell.thirdTimeOption.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[2], forState: .Normal)
    cell.thirdTimeOption.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.thirdTimeOption.hidden = true
}
```

---

Or, if you're like me and hate seeing code repeated like that, you could enumerate through an array of these three buttons:

```
for (index, button) in [cell.firstTimeOption, cell.secondTimeOption, cell.thirdTimeOption].enumerate() {
    if oneResponse.timeOptions.count > index {
        button.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[index], forState: .Normal)
        button.hidden = false
    } else {
        button.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Theoretically you could use an outlet collection to the same end, but I don't use outlet collections where order must be honored.

Comment: OMG, without even telling you that I should remove the buttons in case there is no text, you understood that yourself. you always present the best solutons. you are not just an expert, you are the owner of swift and ios, i thank you very very mych. so lucky to see you in this community. from now and one, you are Rob-the-kind-of-swift-ios

Comment: hello , again please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030123/when-the-right-arrow-is-not-shown-in-my-cell king :)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues before.

**When you debug your program, does that function get called?**

If not, you need to make sure that your ViewController is set at the dataSource delegate.  You can do this in the Main Storyboard by ctrl+click the TableView then dragging it to the left most yellow circle at the top of the view and selecting "dataSource."  This sets that the table view will call all of the necessary functions inside of that class.[image: Click and drag do top button]

Comment: This is a good tip in general, but in this case, if she had neglected to hook up the data source, the `preferencesLabel` wouldn't have been successfully set and the `print` statements wouldn't have shown up in the console.

Comment: Rob is correct, i already have the delegates and the outlets set