# when the right arrow is not shown in my cell

Tags: ios, swift

This is what my story board shows

[image]

However, the right arrow is not there when I run on simulator

[image]

I don't know why and I don't know what code I should show you because I actually didn't make that arrow myself, I just selected the cell's `accessory` as `Discolosure Indicator`

#### update 1

there is no overlap, this is from the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Did you implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? I'm not sure that would affect it, but maybe?

Comment: Make a sample project with the arrow working and compare your sample project to your actual project. Most likely there is some bug that you need to try to isolate.

Comment: @coopersita i added the function, but stil the same problem

Comment: @EpicByte this is  a simple case, i can't be more simplier,

Comment: What Xcode/iOS version are you using?

Comment: @EpicByte Version 7.1.1

Comment: @Rob before making this MCVE, you said something interesting, you said you didn't set the acessryView, actually i set it in the story borad  and i set in code `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator` will that give you any indicatin? or i make this MCVE ?

Comment: @Rob okay i am studying this MCVE and I will tell u when u finish it

Comment: @Rob thanks for the efforts. okay I will do what you said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96740/discussion-between-rob-and-sarah).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you implemented `layoutSubviews`, but never called `super.layoutSubviews()`. Thus the disclosure indicator was never laid out.

Comment: this is for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGJuMBdaqIw you are the firework that destroys any problem thank thank you

Comment: It's very sweet of you, but these sorts of comments really aren't necessary. The checkmark and up-vote are thanks enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside your tableview method

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

//Complete Code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        return cell
 }
```

Comment: i added that, it didn't change anything, sitll the right arrow not showed

Answer (score 0):

try adding disclosure indicator programmatically in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    ...
}
```

Comment: i did that but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using preview in the assistant editor.  Most likely one of the images is overlapping the indicator and you need to adjust your constraints.

Comment: That was my other thought, that the constrains are off, so the indicator is out the screen, or under something.

Comment: no that is not the case, i updated my question to show u that there is no overlapp